# Access WCF service through a Windows Phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, windows-phone-7, azure-sql-database

I am developing a Windows Phone Application and from this application I am accessing an SQL Azure database through a Silverlight-Enabled WCF service. This works perfectly on the Windows Phone emulator. My question is: what will happen when I deploy the application and try to access the WCF service? To test what I have done on a real Windows Phone, do I have to host the site (which includes the WCF service)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are currently hosted on your local machine, then you can still access them by hooking your Windows Phone (must be developer unlocked) and testing your app through Visual Studio

However if you mean deploying to the MarketPlace then yes, you will need to have those services hosted so they can be used by other phones not connected to your local machine.